# SQL Multiply Update Statement Column a x Column b updates c

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I need an update or select statement to do the following

```
SoldOut     RefundIn     UnitCost  Total Cost
   0            1          -1.00     ????
   0            10         -1.00     ????
   1             0          1.00     ????
   10            0         10.00     ????
```

So I want to multiply Units in or Out with Unit Cost to get Total Cost

Comment: If you aren't sure whether you need an UPDATE or a SELECT then you have bigger problems. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use update to store total cost in DB by computing.

```
UPDATE <table name> SET total_cost = UnitCost * (SoldOut-RefundIn)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say never store computed values, too much risk of data inconsistency. Create a view that calculates the computed values.

```
create view view_name as
select SoldOut, RefundIn, UnitCost, (SoldOut - RefundIn) * UnitCost as TotalCost
from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to multiply Units in `or` Out with Unit Cost to get Total Cost

Since you you need to select column with condition, you can use any of the approaches.

**APPROACH 1 : Using dynamic SQL to pass column dynamically**

```
 DECLARE @COLUMNNAME NVARCHAR(100)='RefundIn'

 DECLARE @QRY NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @QRY = 'UPDATE Yourtable  SET [Total Cost] = '+@COLUMNNAME+' * UnitCost'

 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QRY
```

**APPROACH 2 : Using `CASE` statement in your `update` query**

```
 UPDATE Yourtable SET [Total Cost] = CASE WHEN  SoldOut = 0 THEN RefundIn * UnitCost
                                      WHEN  RefundIn = 0 THEN SoldOut * UnitCost
                                 END
```

If you need to hardcode the column name you can use the below code

```
UPDATE Yourtable SET [Total Cost] = RefundIn * UnitCost
```